# RelativeLayout android:clipChildren="false" does not work: Animation will get clipped?

Tags: android, animation, textview, android-relativelayout, clipping

I am trying to implement a scrolling "newsbar". There is a RelativeLayout which fills the screen horizontally. It should contain many different news titles, contained by TextView objects, which I download from the internet and they should be animated in order to slowly moving from right to left, which will generate a "scrolling newsbar" effect. I place the first TextView as RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT and all the consecutive TextViews aligned as RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF according to the previous TextView. So, the text would enter from the right side of the screen and flow through the layout and finally exit from the left side.

I see that the RelativeLayout clips children which are outside of its bounds. I set android:clipChildren="false" for this purpose but it does not function and the TextViews continue to get clipped, which is very annoying and is currently blocking my progress.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Please help me...

Comment: What if you also add `android:clipToPadding="false"`?