# Custom Layout in Android: Which function should I override to get the dimensions of its children?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, ondraw

I am trying to implement a custom layout, which extends RelativeLayout, in order to manage its animating contents. The animation consists of TextViews, scrolling in a newsbar fashion, which I told about in [RelativeLayout android:clipChildren="false" does not work: Animation will get clipped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15798077/relativelayout-androidclipchildren-false-does-not-work-animation-will-get-cl)

After the application has been started, I dowload a list of news titles from the web and I create TextView s and add to this custom layout programmatically. In order to start animating the TextViews, I need their locations and dimensions. So, after adding TextViews to my custom layout, I need to override a function which is called with the children TextViews drawn and having their dimensions correctly set. I tried to override onDraw but it is called only once.

Here is my code:

```
public class NewsAnimationLayout extends RelativeLayout
{

public NewsAnimationLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setWillNotDraw(false);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}


public NewsAnimationLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
        int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    setWillNotDraw(false);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}


public NewsAnimationLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
    setWillNotDraw(false);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

       //Here I will animate child objects.
    }

 };
```

What should I do int this case, can you clarify it to me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Spontaneous thought; wouldn't it be easiest to override the child view classes such that they report their positioning back to their parent view on _their_ `onLayout()` method? I had a look at a `FrameLayout` bug the other day and decided it's not much fun to mess with the core implementation even of `FrameLayout`, so I'd not be eager to manipulate `RelativeLayout` in its, certainly rather complex, child handling core.

Comment: Well, I am confused about what `onMeasured()` and `onLayout()` exactly do. Lets say I am adding child view classes to this custom layout in the Web content callback function, when will those get called? And what are their function: I got lost and confused in Android documentations about them.

Comment: I totally understand you. But it's a matter of twenty minutes or so to subclass the views you are adding to your `NewsAnimationLayout` and see what they'll receive via `onLayout()`. As I understand it, `onLayout()` is what gets called by `layout()` (which is `final` so no path there) in case there are any child views. It gets called if there are _no_ child views, though; so you could use it for your children to report back their positioning within their parent view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I figured it out.

Overriding `onLayout` does the trick, it seems that the Android system calls it whenever we add new children to a ViewGroup in order to deterime their positions and dimensions.

This code in the `NewsAnimationLayout` class reports correct positions and dimensions:

```
@Override
protected void onLayout (boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    super.onLayout(changed,left,top,right,bottom);
    System.out.println("onLayout");
    //Here I will animate child objects.

    int i;
    for(i=0;i<this.getChildCount();i++)
    {
        View v = this.getChildAt(i);

        System.out.println("Child "+i+" X="+v.getX()+" Y="+v.getY());
        System.out.println("Child "+i+" W="+v.getWidth()+" H="+v.getHeight());
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, sure, you don't even have to subclass the child views this way. Glad I could help!